# Joining MySQL Queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am having trouble joining two queries together these are my queries:

```
$sql = "SELECT SourcePath, Description, BikeCode FROM BikeImages order by bikecode";
$sql1 = "SELECT BikeCode, Manufacturer, Model, SubType, Year, FrameMaterial, Description, Gender, Type, Price, Stock FROM Bike WHERE Stock > 0";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
```

Help would be really appreciated, I have had a couple of ideas to join them together such as

```
$result = mysqli_query($sql && $sql1, $con);
```

But it doesn't seem to work, Should I join the two $sql together if so how would I do that?

EDIT: The tables are related because I want to create a while loop, that displays all the information from the Bike table and then grabs the images from the BikeImages table related to each individual BikeCode.

After linking the tables together I wish to use this code to display my information:

```
while(list($bikecode, $manufacturer, $model, $subtype, $year, $fmaterial, $desc, $gender, $type, $price, $stock, $sourcepath, $description) = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)) {   
echo "information here  
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How are the tables related? And what should the result be? Please show some example data.

Comment: As shown in the answers below, you have to write a string that contains a single SELECT statement, which is not as simple as just concatenating to statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using a `JOIN` to join these two tables together.  It appears that `BikeCode` exists in both tables, so you should be able to join the queries similar to this:

```
SELECT b.BikeCode, 
  b.Manufacturer, 
  b.Model, 
  b.SubType, 
  b.Year, 
  b.FrameMaterial, 
  b.Description, 
  b.Gender, 
  b.Type, 
  b.Price, 
  b.Stock,
  i.SourcePath,
  i.Description
FROM Bike b
LEFT JOIN BikeImages i
  on b.bikecode = i.bikecode
WHERE b.Stock > 0
ORDER BY b.BikeCode
```

This then allows you to return all of the data in a single result.

If you need help learning join syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a MySQL JOIN: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html.

Don't do the join in PHP.. it's slower and more complicated.

Nice tutorial here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html